# Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I have `android` `app` in `kotlin` which is giving me this error.

> Error: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
>       class com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth, unresolved supertypes: com.google.android.gms.internal.aad

and this

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

Compilation error. See log for more details

this is my app module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appname"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:26.1.0'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.0.0'



    //noinspection GradleCompatible,GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.0.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

}

 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and my project gradle is this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.51'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I have `firebase.auth implementation` but still, it's showing me the error.

Comment: Have you tried to change the order of your dependencies ?

Answer (score 7):

Updating `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth` to 3.3.1 fixed it for me. As the older versions (3.1.0 in my case) was not compatible with `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging` v15

Comment: Thanks @Rishabh876 implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0' solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

Updating all the dependencies from the "com.google.android.gms:" group and also the firebase-messaging version to 15.0.0. instead of 12.0.1 fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

i see at least 2 problems in your gradle file:

1. You have a duplicated entry for "kotlin-stdlib-jre7" (one implementation and one compile). Remove the last one:

   ```
   compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
   ```
2. Not using the latest versions of firebase & google play services: update to firebase 11.6.2

Answer (score 1):

The other thing that may happen is that you are using `implementation` instead of `api` for one of your dependencies which may conflict with another dependency in your module.

Answer (score 1):

Add following in gradle:-

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using firebase-bom, then you should update to latest version. For me, after upgading to latest it started working.

Lastest version as of now :

> `com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:24.5.0`

You can check latest version [HERE](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android)

Answer (score -2):

add this solves my problem

```
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
```