# "Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved.” in Task:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, ros

I can't compile my Android Kotlin Project because I get the following 'Kotlin compiler' error when gradle compiles:

```
Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure 
you have the required dependencies in the classpath: class 
sensor_msgs.CompressedImage, unresolved supertypes: 
org.ros.internal.message.Message> Task:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug
```

This is a simple test project that has the bare minimum code.  The main difference between a regular android app. and this one is my MainActivity uses class RosActivity rather than AppCompatActivity.

I have changed 'ext.kotlin_version' ([Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54778651/supertypes-of-the-following-classes-cannot-be-resolved-please-make-sure-you-hav))

I have tried changing the order of dependencies ([error: supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598848/error-supertypes-of-the-following-classes-cannot-be-resolved-please-make-sure))

I have tried 'resolutionStrategy.force' ([error: supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598848/error-supertypes-of-the-following-classes-cannot-be-resolved-please-make-sure))

I have tried 'Invalidate cache/restart' ([error: supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598848/error-supertypes-of-the-following-classes-cannot-be-resolved-please-make-sure))

I changed 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin' but this did not work ([Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47676267/supertypes-of-the-following-classes-cannot-be-resolved))

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.company.roscameratest">

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" tools:replace="android:icon">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="org.ros.android.MasterChooser" />

        <service android:name="org.ros.android.NodeMainExecutorService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="org.ros.android.NodeMainExecutorService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle (Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (Module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.company.roscameratest"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force "org.ros.android_core:android_15:0.3.3"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'org.ros.android_core:android_15:0.3.3'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

repositories {
    maven {  url 'https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_mvn_repo/raw/master' }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In gradle， if your Project implementation A， but A also implementation B。 if your project used some class in A whitch extents class in B， you can just call construction method， can‘t call method whitch call superClass in B， or use it to method paramater。

just try implemntation to api。

api 'org.ros.android_core:android_15:0.3.3'

Comment: Thank you 谢金龙.

 
I had found the issue was when I changed from AppCompatActivity to RosActivity. 
Classes were being called in both android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity and androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.  I moved all my controls in my RosActivity form over to android-x and there was no compile error.

 
However, I rolled back and tried using 'api' instead of 'implementation' and this found android=android-x mix, that I previously found via trial-and-error.

Comment: in simple words: say your app module uses dependency on module A (module A has ViewModelOne which extends ViewModelParent), but ViewModelParent is in module B, and you're only implementing module A, so if in your app level gradle you add implemention for both A and B the error will go away. It's not necessary to use api